# If Statements with data attribute - load two different templates based on what product has been clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xml

I would like to open two templates based on the data attribute, if brand is SIM then open template1, if Samsung open the other.

Here is my code:

```
$('.item .show-detail').click(function(){
    if($(this).find('[data-brand="SIM"]')) {
        var myLink1 = $(this);
        alert('hey');
        $('.content .row').fadeOut({complete: function(){detailTemplate1('Voice',$(myLink1).parent().data('brand'), $(myLink1).parent().data('model'), $(myLink1).parent().data('subcat')); $('.content .row').fadeIn(400)}});
    }else
        ($(this).find('[data-brand="Samsung"]'))
        var myLink = $(this);
        alert('link All');
        $('.content .row').fadeOut({complete: function(){detailTemplate('Voice',$(myLink).parent().data('brand'), $(myLink).parent().data('model'), $(myLink).parent().data('subcat')); $('.content .row').fadeIn(400)}});
})
```

Comment: How is it not working, are there any error messages?

Comment: The problem is that, if I click on Sim or Samsung it displays all the alerts that results in loading the first template for both conditions

Comment: You're not wrapping your else statement properly or is it supposed to be an else if?

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of problems in your code.

1. You can't specify a condition for `else`, you have to say `else if`
2. Wrap `else if` block in figure brackets.
3. Use `length` to find if element exists.

This is assuming that data-brands exist inside `item` element you're clicking on:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $('.item').click(function(){

            if( $(this).find('[data-brand="SIM"]').length ) {
                var myLink1 = $(this);
                alert('SIM');
            }
            else if ( $(this).find('[data-brand="Samsung"]').length ) {
                var myLink = $(this);
                alert('Samsung');
            }

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f32epg16/

Comment: The fiddle works but when I add it in my script it doesnt work since I have $('.item .show-detail').click(function()

Answer (score 0):

jquery objects will always be truthy, you need to check the length.

```
if($(this).find('[data-brand="SIM"]').length)
```

Second else does not have a clause. You need to either drop it or use else if.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.item .show-detail').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("data-brand")=="SIM")
            alert("SIM");
        else if($(this).attr("data-brand")=="Samsung")
            alert("Samsung");
   });
});
```

Use jquery attr method to find its value and do the relevant work